# Can I create another user in my window 7 computer to install the ubuntu?

Tags: wubi, windows-7, custom-installer

My computer is window 7 but I would like to try the Ubuntu so can I create another user to install the Ubuntu or just do like the tutorial in Wubi ?

Comment: Hi and Welcome to AskUbuntu. It is not necessary to add another user in order to install Ubuntu via wubi. Just follow the [WubiGuide.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide)

Answer (score 1):

No, You can directly use the **Live Session** to Try the **Ubuntu Os**.

Answer (score -1):

Wubi is not suggested (exept some people who here to tell you different).
Download the ISO file of your prefered version, 12.04 LTS or 12.10 (or earlier).

You can make a disc or a DOK (Disk On Key) by the guides here, and we can also help (:
Boot from the disk/DOK and you will get to a menu with Options to try Ubuntu, install Ubuntu and more.

^^